# Is there a way to rip DVDs & CDs on headless CentOS box?

Tags: linux, centos, dvd, ripping, cd

Has anyone set up headless DVD & CD ripping on a CentOS box? I’ve seen a few posts and threads about other operating systems, but nothing about CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat, and nothing recent.

I’d like to just slide a DVD or CD into my USB player and have it ripped to a temporary folder for review. It would be nice if it pulled the correct metadata from somewhere, but that can come later if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried anything suggested in what you have read?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any software that does it without any human interaction, but you could probably write a script pretty easily.

- [Start off with detecting if a disc has been
  inserted.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359855/how-to-detect-insertion-of-dvd-disc)
- [Use ripit or a similar command to rip CDs.](http://www.maketecheasier.com/rip-cds-at-command-line/)
- [You can also use HandBreakCLI to rip DVDs.](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Using_HandBrakeCLI)
- [Finally, eject the disc when it's done.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226638/how-to-eject-a-cd-dvd-from-the-command-line)

I haven't found a command that would tell you whether the disc is an audio CD or DVD, but you could likely just mount the disc and look at the directory names. If there's a `VIDEO_TS` directory, it's likely a DVD.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the tools available tbh, I'm looking for people that have already done this and can provide bash scripts I can adapt.